# "Identical" code producing different date strings

Tags: angular, date, timezone, picker

I have a page with employee information. Among all the data is a hire date. It's defined as follows:

```
export class Agent {
    public HireDate: Date|any=null;
    // other fields left out
}
```

In the HTML, I've got the following:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Hire Date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="topicker" placeholder="Hire Date" [(ngModel)]="agent.HireDate" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="topicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #topicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I took this from my own code where I had *from* and *to* dates, thus the odd name of `#topicker`. When I had to create a simple incident recorder, I reused more of my own code. Thus I have:

```
export class Incident {
    public Id: number;
    public Occurrence: Date|any = null;
    public Notes: string = '';
}
```

As well as more familiar HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Incident Date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="topicker" placeholder="Incident Date"
        [(ngModel)]="newIncident.Occurrence" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="topicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #topicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

They should all behave the same, right? The first round of code was ok. The second round with the borrowed code was fine. But the last one fails. I traced the network data to the API in both cases and saw this in the payload:

```
HireDate: "2023-08-01T00:00:00"
```

Which is correct. But in the payload for the incident, I saw this:

```
Occurrence: "2023-08-02T05:00:00.000Z"
```

This is arguably correct too, but different. The difference is making the .NET API choke and consider it to be 1-Jan-0001. I considered it possible that I screwed up the POST operation, but I tried dumping contents to the console and I saw a difference before the POST operation.

```
console.log( this.agent );
...

HireDate: "2023-08-01T00:00:00"
```

This matches what goes out the pipe. But logging the other tells me something else:

```
console.log( this.newIncident );
...
Occurrence: > Wed Aug 02 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) {}
```

(The > is the little triangle in the console window.) I get that there can be a difference between a string representation of a date and the date itself. I've tried everything I can think of to convince the two nearly identical bits of code to keep behaving the same, but so far without success.

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the second date is one that you are creating via `new Date()`, but not the first? Native dates in JavaScript aren't intuitive (example article outlining the "gotchas": https://dev.to/zachgoll/a-complete-guide-to-javascript-dates-and-why-your-date-is-off-by-1-day-fi1), and when you create a `Date` instance, you are creating it based on the client's (i.e. the user's) computer's local time.

It is generally always advisable to use a library such as `date-fns` (https://date-fns.org/). Historically, `moment.js` was the most popular, however that project is now in "maintenance mode", and considered somewhat legacy, due to the way it works. Further alternatives mentioned here: https://blog.openreplay.com/dealing-with-dates-and-times--alternatives-to-momentjs/. These libraries will allow you to work with dates with greater control, most notably being able to create dates without worrying what the user's local time/timezone is.

The `Z` suffixed to the serialized `Occurrence` date indicates that the timepart is UTC (the Z indicates Zulu time, which is largely the same), i.e. a `0` offset.

Whilst it is sometimes desired to use "local" times with dates (e.g. if a user is specifying the exact moment something will happen, not just the day), when you want a midnight date (i.e. the timepart is not relevant) then you want to be using UTC for both user input, display, and storage. Displaying a "timeless" date not in UTC will result in the wrong day being shown for "negative offset" timezones (e.g. PST, EST, etc). To do this, one of the main steps is that you want the Moment datepicker to use UTC - you can do this via `useUtc` on `MAT_MOMENT_ADAPTER_DATE_OPTIONS`, see https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview.

At a high-level your next steps should be:

- Ensure your date input is configured to use UTC (in your case, Moment will allow this via configuration).
- Ensure that your API is expecting your `DateTime` objects to be in UTC.
- When displaying the date anywhere, ensure that it is being displayed as UTC, and not local time.
- When working with dates in JavaScript, use a library such as `date-fns` (Material now supports this too). Particularly when you create a date, as you want to create it as UTC, and not in the user's system time.

Failure to do this can mean:

- Incorrect and unreliable user input of dates (it can vary depending on the user's timezone)
- Displaying of the wrong date to the user (often this manifests in, for example, North American users seeing a day earlier than expected)